# import arcgisscripting gives ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-9.3, windows-7, 64bit

i am trying to import arcgisscripting and getting following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import arcgisscripting
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I have windows 7 64 bits, i have installed python-2.7.3.amd64, pywin32-219.win-amd64-py2.7
and using arcgis9.3. i have set pythonpath accordingly which is set to python and arcgis/bin folder as well. But still getting the same error.

I have spent almost whole day to fix this issue and tried all the exisiting solutions but didnt get any success, i think my arcgis 9.3 is not 64 bits.

Comment: I think you should install Python 2.5 and it should be 32bit since ArcGIS of 9.3 is a 32 bit application. Try installing the Python which comes together with ArcGIS installation media and setting the path accordingly.

Comment: @NeilAyres I think it's probably only worth mentioning that if you include a [link](https://geonet.esri.com/message/434928#434928) too.  Without the link it means any potential answerers are likely to all be doing the same search there.

Answer (score 3):

As [commented by @AlexTereshenkov](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120686/import-arcgisscripting-gives-importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win/121137#comment171873_120686) installing a 64bit version of Python 2.7.3 with ArcGIS Desktop 9.3 is ill advised.

If you uninstall ArcGIS Desktop and Python, and then let ArcGIS Desktop install Python for you I suspect you will be up and running within an hour.

As you can see from the [System Requirements for ArcGIS Desktop 9.3/9.3.1](http://downloads.esri.com/support/systemrequirements/ArcGIS_Desktop_93_SystemRequirements.pdf) the Python version needed appears to be 2.5.1:

> **Python Requirement for Geoprocessing**:
>   Several ArcGIS geoprocessing tools, such as Multiple Ring Buffer, use the Python
>   scripting language and require that Python is installed. If the ArcGIS
>   Desktop, Engine or Server setups do not find Python 2.5.1 on the
>   target computer, it will install Python 2.5.1 plus Numerical Python
>   1.0.3 during a typical or complete installation. You may choose a Custom installation to unselect the Python feature to avoid installing
>   this feature. See the install guide for additional information
>   concerning Python.